# How to count XML tags of a document created with a servlet

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, xml, servlets

I've created a servlet that use a class to convert the ResultSet of a mysql query in XML and return that XML to the browser. I can parse it correctly navigating with Javascript in the XML DOM but i can't count how much tags are in the document, because i obtain always "undefined" as value. Can anyone can help me to fix this ?

I post the XML response and the javascript source

```
function newXMLHttpRequest() {
    var request = null;
    var browser = navigator.userAgent.toUpperCase();
    if(typeof(XMLHttpRequest) === "function" || typeof(XMLHttpRequest) === "object") {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if(window.ActiveXObject && browserUtente.indexOf("MSIE 4") < 0) {
        if(browser.indexOf("MSIE 5") < 0) {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } else {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    return request;
            }

function search_actor(){
    var name = document.getElementById("actname").value;
    if(name == "")
        document.getElementById("risultati").innerHTML = "Inserisci un valore nel campo di ricerca";
    else{
        var req = newXMLHttpRequest();
        req.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(req.readyState == 4){
                if(req.status == 200){
                    getData(req.responseXML);
                }
                else if(req.status == 204){
                    delete_suggest();
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    req.open("POST", "GetActors", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    var params = "name=" + escape(name);
    req.send(params);
}

//debug function
function xml_to_string(xml_node)
{
    if (xml_node.xml)
        return xml_node.xml;
    else if (XMLSerializer)
    {
        var xml_serializer = new XMLSerializer();
        return xml_serializer.serializeToString(xml_node);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("ERROR: Extremely old browser");
        return "";
    }
}

function getData(responseXML){
    delete_suggest();
    var prec_risultati = document.getElementById("risultati");
    // Se la risposta non è nulla
        // Punto alla radice della risposta
        var risposta = responseXML.getElementsByTagName('first_name');
        var lenghtr = risposta.lenght;
        document.getElementById("risultati").innerHTML = lenghtr;
        if(lenghtr > 0){
            for(x = 0; x < lenghtr; x++ ){
                var valori = risposta[x].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                var row = document.createElement("tr");
                var td = document.createElement("td");
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(valori));
                row.appendChild(td);
                prec_risultati.appendChild(row);
            }
        }
}

function delete_suggest(){
    document.getElementById("risultati").innerHTML = "";
}
```

The XML response is similar to

```
<results><row><actor_id>10</actor_id><first_name>CHRISTIAN</first_name><last_name>GABLE</last_name><last_update>2006-02-15 04:34:33.0</last_update></row><row><actor_id>21</actor_id><first_name>KIRSTEN</first_name><last_name>PALTROW</last_name><last_update>2006-02-15 04:34:33.0</last_update></row></results>
```

I want to count how much rows are in this XML and i've test

```
responseXML.getElementsByTagName("row").lenght
responseXML.getElementsByTagName("row")[0].lenght
responseXML.getElementsByTagName("row").childNodes.lenght
```

but all of these return me undefined. Someone can help me?

Comment: Did you try `length` instead of `lenght`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I can't test it from here, but it seems that you have misspelled the **length** command.

It should be `responseXML.getElementsByTagName("row").length;`

For further details check out this example:
http://acsummer.wordpress.com/2007/12/30/quick-answers-count-the-number-of-child-elements-in-dom/